# Ionic, angular, resets radio button group in ng repeat every time $state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, radio-button

I have and iOS app in ionic, there is one view that displays a list of products, each product is an object and have two promo price items, they are the radio group values.

The thing is, i have tried EVERYTHING, but every time i click the product to go to product sub page and then go back to products list, the radio group is always reset, it even don't have it initial state of first radio checked, just not checked at all.

```
<ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="p in All" ng-click="pGo(p)">
        <div ng-include="'views/prods/p_item.html'"></div>
    </ion-item>

   $scope.pGo = function (p) {
        $state.go("app.prodOne", { ID: p.id });
    }
```

I have tried (all are a part of template inside ng repeat, p_item.html):

```
     <!--<ion-radio icon="ion-checkmark-circled" name="loyalC{{p.id}}" ng-model="p.loyalType" ng-value="p.pkt_id">{{p.kprice_many + "zł + " + p.kprice_pkt}} pkt</ion-radio>

                <ion-radio icon="ion-checkmark-circled" name="loyalC{{p.id}}" ng-model="p.loyalType" ng-value="p.pkt_id2">{{p.kprice_many2 + "zł + " + p.kprice_pkt2}} pkt</ion-radio>-->
```

---

```
                <!--<ion-radio icon="ion-checkmark-circled"  value="{{p.pkt_id}}" ng-checked="{{true}}">{{p.kprice_many + "zł + " + p.kprice_pkt}} pkt</ion-radio>

                <ion-radio icon="ion-checkmark-circled"  value="{{p.pkt_id2}}">{{p.kprice_many2 + "zł + " + p.kprice_pkt2}} pkt</ion-radio>-->
```

---

```
                <!--<label class="item item-radio"><input name="{{p.id}}" type="radio" value="{{p.pkt_id}}" checked><div class="radio-content"><div class="item-content disable-pointer-events"><span>{{p.kprice_many + "zł + " + p.kprice_pkt}} pkt</span></div><i class="radio-icon disable-pointer-events icon ion-checkmark-circled"></i></div></label>

                <label class="item item-radio"><input name="{{p.id}}" type="radio" value="{{p.pkt_id2}}"><div class="radio-content"><div class="item-content disable-pointer-events"><span>{{p.kprice_many2 + "zł + " + p.kprice_pkt2}} pkt</span></div><i class="radio-icon disable-pointer-events icon ion-checkmark-circled"></i></div></label>-->
```

---

```
                <input name="{{p.id}}" type="radio" value="{{p.pkt_id}}" checked>
                <input name="{{p.id}}" type="radio" value="{{p.pkt_id2}}">
```

NOTHING, just nothing works.

The p.loyalType is the model value for radio of this product object and has initial value of p.pkt_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for everyone, i will spare you hours of pain, DO NOT use any other data in radio names in this kind of functionality other than **$index** eg

```
name="radio-{{$index}}"
```

Don't know why and how, but only this works. It is something internal i guess.